# How to change the popup.html from the js file?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am a newbie, I am trying to make a Chrome extension that notifies the user to take a break after every one hour. I had made an SVG loader that has some text that shows the user how much time is left for the next break, There's a background.js file that runs and changes the popup.html code, but error is coming:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null
```

Here's my manifest.json:-

```
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Detox",
  "version": "0.1",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["index.js"]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_title": "Detox your schedule"
  }
}
```

Here's my background.js, the error is coming on the third line:-

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  var time = 3600;
  var showTime = document.querySelector("#timeFromBreak").textContent;

  setInterval(function () {
    if (time > 0) {
      let mins = Math.floor(time / 60);
      let sec = time % 60;
      showTime = mins + ":" + sec;
      time -= 1;
    } else {
      showTime = "BREAKTIME!!!";
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

and here's popup.html:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>extension</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Your Detox Report</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
      <section class="titlePage">
        <div class="nbi">Next Break In</div>
        <svg height="100" width="100" style="transform: rotate(270deg);">
          <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" />
          <text
            id="timeFromBreak"
            text-anchor="middle"
            x="50"
            y="-50"
            fill="#2bae66ff"
            transform="rotate(90)"
          >
            1:00
          </text>
        </svg>
      </section>
    </main>
    <script src="./background.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're seeing the error in chrome://extensions page in which case it comes from index.js, which you don't need.

1. Remove `background` section from manifest.json
2. Store the DOM element in `showTime` and then assign its textContent property. Currently you change the text itself, which is just a plain string that's not connected to the element anymore

   ```js
     var showTime = document.querySelector("#timeFromBreak");

     setInterval(function () {
       if (time > 0) {
         let mins = Math.floor(time / 60);
         let sec = time % 60;
         showTime.textContent = mins + ":" + sec;
         time -= 1;
       } else {
         showTime.textContent = "BREAKTIME!!!";
       }
     }, 1000);
   ```
3. rename background.js to popup.js (also inside the tag in popup.html)

Note that the popup is a standard page shown in its own separate window so it has its own separate devtools, which you can invoke by right-clicking inside the popup.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! This has helped me a lot! : )